# Can't get CKeditor to work with laravel i guess i need to use asset() but i'm not sure how

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, ckeditor4.x

i downloaded the ckeditor package with composer but when i add `<script src="/vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>` in blade template it says 404 he can't find it but it exists

Comment: <script src="{{asset('/vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}}s"></script>

Comment: Assuming you install and publish correctly, ``<script src="{{ asset('vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js) }}"></script>``